# Hide ag-grid status bar

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

This question is concerning the status bar for ag-grid that comes with the Enterprise Edition.  I'm currently using ag-grid-community 19.1 with Angular 7.

I'm looking for the best way to suppress the status-bar? When I don't include the `statusBar` grid option at all I'm still seeing empty space at the bottom of my grid (although it is blank), where the status bar should be.  Inspecting the generated HTML reveals the existence of this:

```
<!--AG-STATUS-BAR-->
<div class="ag-status-bar" ref="statusBar">
    <div ref="eStatusBarLeft" class="ag-status-bar-left"></div>
    <div ref="eStatusBarCenter" class="ag-status-bar-center"></div>
    <div ref="eStatusBarRight" class="ag-status-bar-right"></div>
</div>
```

Now if I removed that section completely in the Chrome console it disappears as desired.  But I've tried doing this via css but it doesn't seem to work:

```
.ag-status-bar {
    height: 0px;
}
```

Honestly, I'd prefer a way of doing it programmatically via a setting in the `statusBar` grid option but I don't see anything like that in the ag-grid documentation.

Any help is appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not setting `statusBar` on grid options should be enough to the status bar not to appear.

So, I see no other option than via css do the following:

```
.ag-status-bar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This solution does indeed work (although as a note I had to put this at the very top css level in my Angular app for it to take effect).  If no other grid option solutions are posted I'll accept this as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> When I don't include the statusBar grid option at all I'm still seeing empty space at the bottom of my grid (although it is blank), where the status bar should be.

Agreed. When I don't include it in `gridOptions`, it shouldn't come at all. But anyways, I'll provide whatever I've found thinking it'd be helpful to somebody.
 BTW, the mark-up would still be there in the DOM. So the [answer @Diogo Rocha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53674770/1417185) has provided would be the proper solution, if you don't even what to see it in any case.

---

You can change its visibility programmatically by accessing [Accessing Status Bar Panel Instances](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-status-bar-component/#accessing-status-bar-comp-instances)

```
toggleStatusBarComp() {
   let statusBarComponent = this.gridApi.getStatusPanel("statusBarCompKey");
   let componentInstance = statusBarComponent;
   if (statusBarComponent.getFrameworkComponentInstance) {
     componentInstance = statusBarComponent.getFrameworkComponentInstance();
   }
   componentInstance.setVisible(!componentInstance.isVisible());
}
```

Have a look at this example in the documentation: [Get Status Bar Panel Instance](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-status-bar-component/#example-component-instance)

Comment: So in this case the toggle assumes that you **actually have** a status bar to begin with, correct?  Whereas in my scenario I don't want one at all?

Comment: Correct, I've provided the answer for others who might reach here for this after googling... As mentioned in my answer, the other answer provided makes sense for your scenario

Comment: Gotcha; I just wanted to make sure I was understanding you correctly.  This is helpful, however, and related in my opinion.